# JavaScript cannot find custom module

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to run a custom module in node.js, but for some reason it spits out this error:

```
Require stack:
- C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sitev\Site\general.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15
)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:999:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Sitev\Site\general.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1097:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1149:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:975:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_ma
in:81:12) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\Administrator\\Desktop\\Sitev\\Site\\genera
l.js'
  ]
}

Node.js v17.1.0
```

Thing is the thing im trying to require is right there

I tried everything, Here is combinations of require that i tried

```
require(".\page_serve")
require(".\page_serve.js")
require("./page_serve")
require("./page_serve.js")
require("page_serve")
require("page_serve.js")
```

I tried all of them but still the same error

[image: Right there]

Operating system is windows server 2012

Comment: Please, update with your require line from general.js

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the variable itself.
Correct one should be:

```
let page_serve = require("./page_serve")
```